# LaTeX typesetting error

Tags: errors, equations

I have this code but whenever I run it, I get an error but I still can't seem to find what I wrong with it.

```
\begin{equation}

ET=\dfrac{1}{\lambda\rho_w}\dfrac{\Delta(R_n-G)+{\rho_a}c_p
   \dfrac{e_s-e_a}{r_a}}{\Delta+\gamma(1+\dfrac{r_s}{r_a})}

\end{equation}
```

this is the equation I am trying to type out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Do please tell which error message(s) you get.

Answer (score 5):

Every `\par` command, which can be also an empty line, is forbidden in math mode and produces a proper error. For `\dfrac` command you  need `amsmath` package. The following code compiles without errors.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  ET=\dfrac{1}{\lambda\rho_w}\dfrac{\Delta(R_n-G)+{\rho_a}c_p\dfrac{e_s-e_a}{r_a}}{\Delta+\gamma(1+\dfrac{r_s}{r_a})}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, it needs, e.g.,  `\left[` ... `\right]` and `\left(` ... `\right)` pairs to obtain parentheses.

Comment: I am really new to LateX and I do not understand your response. Could you please clarify it? Thanks

Comment: @xoxo The initial one or the present version?

Comment: @xoxo You are welcome. Please observe however, that the present result is far away from this from your picture. But the code compiles and you can work on it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer code, but with `\boxed` to have a framed box around the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \boxed{\mathrm{ET}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda\rho_w}\left[\dfrac{\Delta(R_n-G)+{\rho_a}c_p\dfrac{e_s-e_a}{r_a}}{\Delta+\gamma\left(1+\dfrac{r_s}{r_a}\right)}\right]}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]